# Select features using a selected feature in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, select-by-location, feature-extraction

Using a selected feature is it possible to select from a separate file to then extract?

In this case I'm trying to extract points from within a given parish using a whole country parish layer.

Answer (score 2):

To do this I would filter the parishes layer to a single parish using a definition query.

Then you can use that layer with your point layer as inputs to Select Layer By Location.